# Ubuntu 20,04,4 LTS starts computer up from full shutdown on it's own

Tags: startup

Three day old fresh install on an old HP Elite i7-2600. I shut it down at night, and it's running in the morning. Shut it down again, and it's on when I get home from work. Is this a setting or a bug? Thanks!

Comment: Modern computers have the ability to start by clock time, when enabled. You should check your BIOS for any such setting. Usually an operating system is able to program the BIOS clock times for such automatic start. So it would also be a good idea to check any program in Ubuntu which is capable of doing so. In it's default settings, Ubuntu is not doing such things. So you must have enabled this by your own. Another explanation would be that the power switch of your computer has a malfunction.

Comment: Do you have Wake-on-LAN enabled in the BIOS/UEFI? 

Comment: My machine was set to power on in the BIOS. Thanks for the help!